# linq to sql navigation properties simple example

Tags: c#, linq

For this kind of schema:

```
mainTable(Id,Name) //Id is primary key

secondryTable(mainTableId,RegDate,Age) // mainTableId is foreign key
```

Can anyone give me a example of Linq to Sql using navigation properites.

With join I am selecting as:

```
from mainT in db.mainTable
join secT in db.secondryTable on mainT.Id equals secT.mainTableId
select new { mainT.Name, secT.RegDate, secTable.Age}
```

Comment: If you scroll down, the Person class contains a property `public City BornInCity { get; set; }`. I presume the City class has a Name property as well. So, `p.BornInCity.Name` makes sense from that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own :) The query would be:

```
FROM mainT in db.mainTable
SELECT new
    {
      mainT.Name,
      regDate = mainT.secT.Where(//some condition),
      age = mainT.secT.Where(//some condition)
    }
```

The above query is valid only if the Primary key/Foreign key relationships are defined properly in database.